# How do I center the content of this website?

Tags: html, css, layout, center

So I've been doing a website for an assignment and for some reason I can't seem to align the content of the website. it's a simple layout. It's pure content no sidebars or anything. Here'es the HTML for the content:

```
     <!-- Begin Content Column -->
     <div id="content">

          <img src="img8.png" style="width: 460px; height: 100px;" alt="pokemon">
          <br>Pokemon:
          The First Movie 
          <br>Soundtracks

     </div>
     <!-- End Content Column -->
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
background: black;
font-family: Trajan Pro,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 28px;
text-align: center;
background-image: url('img2.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom center;
background-size: 460px 300px; 

}

#content { 
float: left;
color: #333;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 1024px;
width: 460px;
display: inline;

}
```

Thank you all in advance. I'm trying to align the content's image to the background's image to make like a fading effect, but can't center the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style of content to

display:inline;

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do is remove `float: left;` and `display: inline;` from the `#content` css selector.

Comment: Thank you so much. First year coding.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left;` from `#content` and add `display:block;` to it. That should center it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from the CSS #content :

```
display: inline;
float: left;
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and easy explanation.